# How to install Rethinkdb in Ubuntu?

Tags: 18.04, database, software-uninstall

I have installed Rethinkdb for a project I am doing with `Node.js` following the steps of the [Rethinkdb website](https://www.rethinkdb.com/docs/install/ubuntu/).

But after executing `rethinkdb` in terminal inside the folder `/rethinkdb-2.3.6`, it returns:

```
rethinkdb: order not found
```

As I say, I followed the steps of the web, on another occasion I worked, but in this one in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS I did not get installed.

Is there any other documentation that I can follow for the correct installation?

Forgive the syntax, I must use the translator.
Thank you.

EDIT:

When I try `sudo apt-get install rethinkdb`, it returns:

```
package not found
```

I saw something about "brew" to install rethinkdb on Mac, I do not know if it can be an alternative for Ubuntu.

Comment: when I type `apt search rethinkdb`, I got 1 result : `golang-gopkg-dancannon-gorethink.v1-dev`, which refers to "RethinkDB driver for Go". Don't know if this package is that you want or no

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to install Rethinkdb on Ubuntu 18.04 with the help of a project collaborator and locate on GitHub, which I think is necessary for Obionic and can install with dpkg -i,
and then following the steps that are normally followed for the compilation, which are described in the official Rethinkdb website:
https://rethinkdb.com/docs/install/ubuntu/
I leave the link of the site where I get the .deb file
https://github.com/srh/rethinkdb/releases/tag/v2.3.6.srh.1
  Thanks for the help given by all, which made me keep looking for a way to solve the problem, and it took me to GitHub, which was where I found a solution.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

As I checked, the rethinkdb not have package for Bionic release (18.04). In this situation you should build the package yourself as is described on the official documentation web page: https://rethinkdb.com/docs/build/

Comment: Are you sure you looks on this link which I provided for you in my earlier comment? I think, no.

Comment: Man, doubt offends ... @mariaczi..., I have already tried three times and it always gives me: Err: 7 http://donload.rethinkdb.com/apt bionic Release
404 Not Found [Ip: .....]
N: You can not update repository like this securely, it is disabled
N: See the apt-secure (8) man page for details on creating repositories

Comment: Yeah, Man. As you now known that rethinkdb not offer repository for Bionic release you should remove or disable this repo on you machine :) and after you have had this done apt will work well.

Comment: If you follow on instruction, you should remove this file: `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/rethinkdb.list`

Comment: Please, read with understanding. As I wrote, you must install this software from sources as you have described in documentation on the provided link by me. It is not possible to install rethinkdb using apt/apt-get as the author not provide packages for Bionic release.

Comment: Hello, this is what is in the instructions: source /etc/lsb-release && echo "deb http://download.rethinkdb.com/apt $DISTRIB_CODENAME main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/rethinkdb.list
wget -qO- https://download.rethinkdb.com/apt/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rethinkdb And it shows apt-get install rethinkdb

Comment: https://rethinkdb.com/docs/build/ this is the link for instruction how to build from sources you should use